# How do I git reset --hard HEAD on Mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial, merge, dvcs

I'm a Git user trying to use Mercurial.

Here's what happened: I did a `hg backout` on a changeset I wanted to revert. That created a new head, so hg instructed me to merge (back to "default", I assume). After the merge, it told me I still had to commit. Then I noticed something I did wrong when resolving a conflict in the merge, and decided I wanted to have everything as before the `hg backout`, that is, I want this uncommited merge to go away. On Git this uncommited stuff would be in the index and I'd just do a `git reset --hard HEAD` to wipe it out but, from what I've read, the index doesn't exist on Mercurial. So how do I back out from this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of some changeset in Hg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172753/how-to-get-rid-of-some-changeset-in-hg)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

If you've not yet commited, and it sounds like you haven't you can undo all the merge work with `hg update --clean`.

However, in newer mercurial's there's a handy command to re-merge a single file: `hg resolve path/to/file.ext`.  From the `hg help resolve`:

> ```
> The available actions are: ...
>
>  4) discard your current attempt(s) at resolving conflicts and
> ```
>
> restart
>            the merge from scratch: "hg resolve file..." (or "-a" for all
>            unresolved files)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused: I ran `hg up -C`, but the "backed out" commit is still at the tip of my branch. I thought this was a "ghost branch" that got created with the `backout`, but running `hg branch` returns `default`, so I'm on the main branch after all?

Comment: You can have two heads with the same branch, and that's what you've got.  They're both named `default`.  This is a very normal situation in mercurial and '
`hg heads` is the command you use to discover/understand it.

When you ran `hg backout` it "Commit the backed out changes as a new changeset" so that created a new changeset that won't go away w/o heroic effort.  So now you have two heads both on the branch named default.  After you `hg merge` (and commit it) you'll be back to one head on the branch named default.

Answer (score 26):

This is close:

`hg update --clean`

Comment: yeah... sometimes though when you move files around (from one directory to another) and then decide to scratch everything, it does not do the same thing as `git reset --hard` would do. Ergo - mercurial is stupid

Answer (score 14):

From git, commands:

```
git reset --hard     # reset to last commit    
git clean -df        # delete untracked files
```

are equal to

```
hg update --clean    # reset to last commit  
hg purge             # delete untracked files
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: `git reset --hard` doesn't delete untracked files.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `hg update --clean 18:8e139889ff02` says "updated 2 files", however when I look at the log, it's still where it was. **UPD**: that said, it did reset the files to the revision. Which is only half of the `git reset --hard` behavior though.

Answer (score 13):

The Hg Manual’s [GitConcepts](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts) page explains how to do many actions `git` users are familiar with in Mercurial.

Mercurial doesn’t have any built-in `git reset --hard` behavior. However, the `strip` extension provides a `strip` command which does. To use, [first enable `strip`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension#Configuration) in your `~/.hgrc` file::

```
[extensions]
strip =
```

*Note: this extension is shipped in new in Mercurial 2.8. Prior versions provided the `strip` command in the [`mq` extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension#Configuration).*

Now you can run commands like `hg strip` or even `hg help strip`. To remove a changeset and all of its children, simply specify that changeset as an argument to `hg strip`. For example, to remove the last commit you just made (after you used commands which caused `hg rollback` to report that there is no longer any transaction to rollback), you can remove the `tip` revision. Each time you run this command, another revision will be removed. *`hg strip`’s actions should be considered irreversible; unfamiliar users should make backups of their repositories before using.*

```
$ hg strip tip
```

For example, with [revsets syntax](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets), I indicate that I want to remove any commits of mine which result in extra heads being shown when I run `hg heads`. If you specify a particular revision in the below expression other than `tip`, everything in the current branch that is not an ancestor of your chosen revision will be trimmed. This seems closest to the behavior I want when I issue the command `git reset --hard HEAD`.

```
$ hg strip "branch(tip) and not(ancestors(tip)::tip)"
```

Comment: Mercurial 2.8 and above has a ``strip`` extension in case one only wants the ``hg strip`` command explicitly.  Using ``mq`` adds a variety of other patch management commands as well.

Comment: In TortoiseHg 4.7 and above, this can be enabled using File > Settings > Extensions and then check strip, and restarting TortoiseHg.  Then View > ShowConsole, to get the command line to type in e.g. hg strip --keep -r 50

Comment: strip worked fine, but in my case i didn't have `~/.hgrc` so add it in `mercurial.ini` file

Answer (score 1):

What I expected to find as an alternative to `git reset --hard` in mercurial was:

```
hg strip --keep -r . # --keep optional
hg update --clean    # reset to last commit
```

And then if you need too:

```
hg purge
```

Comment: `hg purge` will unconditionally delete all untracked files, including those that were untracked before the `hg update --clean`. `git reset --hard` only affects staged files.