# How to uncommit in mercurial for my last commit

Tags: mercurial

How can I undo my last accidentally commited (not pushed) change in Mercurial?
I can't use

```
hg rollback
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial: how to undo last unpushed commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223639/mercurial-how-to-undo-last-unpushed-commit)

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable strip extension
2. Read `hg help strip`
3. Strip bad commit